# Is there risk of corruption of comments added in a notebook outside Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks

For  various reasons, I'm placing data before and after notebook's source code, by means of a plain text editor, in this way:

```
(*
Author: An author
Subject: A subject
*)

(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)
...
(* End of internal cache information *)

(* more data *)
```

Are there conceivable situations in which these data can be lost or damaged, during the normal Mathematica's activity ? If any, can, please, you suggest a safer way to embed the above mentioned data in a notebook, keeping them simple ?

A similar question has been debated in: [How to programmatically comment out multiple source files?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22221/how-to-programmatically-comment-out-multiple-source-files) 
where reads "*As the comments of Szabolcs and acl tell you: read in the file contents as text, put the comment characters before-after the text and save it again as text. Packages are stored as plain text files without any front-end dependent cache information, so this method is robust and foolproof.*", but the this time the focus is on notebook, not packages.

What explained in [Is there a way to embed a data set in a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79561/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-data-set-in-a-notebook) seems IMHO not pertinent, just because the minimalistic formattation is inescapably required.

Comment: You can use TaggingRules.

Comment: Thanks for yor lightning reply ! I don't trust TaggingRules, at the aim we are talnking about, because it does "something" potentially alterable by Mathematica's code unexpected side effects. Am I missing something ?

Comment: It should be OK. It's essentially the same method that _Mathematica_'s  package development template uses to embed meta-date into `.m` files.

Comment: It's no strictly relevant but  readers interested in this topic may find useful this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/695/what-is-the-purpose-of-tags-like-name-context-etc-in-packages