# Why do I get "There appers to be an error in the file named below"?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

For first time in my life, I have just suffered the error: " "*There appears to be an error in the file named below*".

[image: screenshoot]

"*Parse and load the entire notebook upon opening.*", doesn't help.

I have saved the notebook as a plain text file and opened it an text editor; and I have come upon that the documentation header, javaDoc fashioned, that I have added above

```
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)
```

is broken up in pieces scatterd everywhere inside the text.

```
(*@@

@ user data DTD...........: 
@ short description.......: 
@ project.................: 
@ author..................:
@ status..................: 
@ todo....................: 
@ changelog...............: 
@ tag.....................: 

@@*)
```

Perhaps Mathematica can't parse such a code: do you know any alternative    interpretation ?

Comment: So you've added something manually to the file first?

Comment: Yes, only what is described above.

Comment: I'm not experienced with that so tell me why you think you can add this header?

Comment: I want to use it as a standardized description header,  processed using an automatic documentation tool, to generate report both within notebooks and in html/xml format.

Comment: I wasn't able to find good example in docs but maybe .nb file needs it's structure and one is not supposed to modify it manually. I'd ask WRI. Furthermore I wouldn't say that this is a bug since you've done something undocumented to the file.

Comment: I will remove [tag:bugs] not because I think so but because the convention is that it first have to be confirmed somehow.

Comment: This QA may be relevant http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107623/is-there-risk-of-corruption-of-comments-added-in-a-notebook-outside-mathematica

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38403/discussion-between-mitochondrial-and-kuba).